# Unable to start activity when calling activity from fragment using intent?

Tags: android

03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739): Process: com.h3ck.choicemobileno, PID: 29739
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.h3ck.choicemobileno/com.h3ck.choicemobileno.FragmentTwo}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1541)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3957)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3932)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1054)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1033)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at com.h3ck.choicemobileno.FragmentTwo.onContextItemSelected(FragmentTwo.java:146)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at android.app.Fragment.performContextItemSelected(Fragment.java:1821)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchContextItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:1986)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2623)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3878)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
03-04 16:37:49.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29739):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)

```
Intent nt = new Intent(view.getContext().getApplicationContext(),
            FragmentTwo.class);
    startActivity(nt);
    getActivity().finish();

Intent nt = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            FragmentTwo.class);
    startActivity(nt);
    getActivity().finish();

Intent nt = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            FragmentTwo.class);
    startActivity(nt);
    getActivity().finish();

    /*FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    FragmentTwo llf = new FragmentTwo();
    ft.replace(R.id.reservemobiledata, llf);
    ft.commit();
    */


    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FragmentTwo.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

If any one have solution then please post your precious solution....

Comment: instead of "this" in  pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
use getActivity();

Answer (score 0):

you would add it in the onCreateView method on the view you want to add it

like

```
yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @override public onClick(View view) { ... } });
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what are you try to do in your code, but you can do

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements OnClickListener
```

and add unimplemented methods to override an onClick method.